# Docx file corrupted when adding an image with python docx

Tags: python, docx

I am trying to do the following:

- read an existing docx (word) file (could be very simple, with just one row of plain text)
- add an image (.jpg, .png, .gif, it doesn't matter)
- save a new docx file with the attached image
- convert the new docx into pdf

The submitted code is the following:

---

```
import docx
from docx2pdf import convert

test = docx.Document('test.docx')

test.add_picture(firma_jpg)

test.save('test_2.docx')

convert('test_2.docx','test.pdf')
```

---

Last instruction produce an error, because the new docx file (test_2.docx) is corrupted.

When I try to open the new file with Word it seems to be corrupted. However, forcing Word to open I get the the expected file.

Any idea how to fix the corrupted docx issue or how to handle it when converting to pdf?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I have found this solution. https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/455